# Replace a String containing "$" with "\$" in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

How can I do it? I made a research but I could not find a clear answer.I tried to use

```
pass = pass.replaceAll("$", "\\$");
```

but It does not work.

Comment: Can you please post input and desired output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
pass = pass.replace("$", "\\$");
```

It will also replace all occurrences. See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

If you prefer the hard way and want to use a regex, you need:

```
pass = pass.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

This can be simplified with `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` but still, only use `replaceAll()` when you need to replace something that matches a regular expression, and use `replace()` when you have to replace a literal sequence.

Comment: And I will remove my incorrect comment about replaceAll.  Thank you, @jlordo, and sorry that your comment will be hanging in the air.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses regular expressions, where both `\` and `$` have special meanings. You don't want that as far as I can tell - you just want to replace the strings verbatim. As such, you should use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
pass = pass.replace("$", "\\$");
```

(Personally I think the fact that `replaceAll` uses regular expressions is a design mistake, but that's another matter.)

Comment: I'm fully agreeing with your statement regarding the naming of the `String` method. The fact that the method actually does not replace anything in the original string could also be seen as a design mistake. This is a question of convenience vs learning curve I suppose. `replaceUsingRegularExpressionReturningANewString()` may not be the way to go either :P

Comment: @owlstead: I'm not *too* bothered by the fact that it doesn't mutate the string - learning that strings are immutable is a pretty fundamental part of learning Java. (Admittedly `withReplacement` or something similar would be cleaner.) But `replaceAll` as a name gives no hint whatsoever that it's going to use a regex... I still need to check each time when I'm using `replace` or `replaceAll` which method does which.